# Cannot connect to node externally

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, express

I am currently trying to connect to a local server and have node run an app on port 8080. I have node and apache installed. When apache is switched on I am able to connect to the apache server externally. However when node is running and apache is stopped I cannot connect externally. I can however connect locally to node even when apache s running. Here is the code I am using:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var mysql = require('mysql');


var connectionpool = mysql.createPool({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'development',
    port: 3306,
    connectionLimit: 50
});
var UAParser = require('ua-parser-js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
})); // pull information from html in POST                       // pull information from html in POST


require('./config/signup.js')(app, express, connectionpool, UAParser);

//Setup for external access

var http = require('http');


var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8080);

console.log('Rest Demo Listening on port 8080');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I actually had it connecting externally yesterday evening briefly.

Comment: What do you mean? Is apache proxying port 80 to 8080 or something? What url are you trying to use to access the node server?

Comment: Apache is running on port 80 but the port forwarding sends all requests from port 8080 to port 80. If that makes any sense

Comment: What url are you using then when Apache is stopped? Are you including port 8080 in it or are you still trying to connect to port 80?

Comment: no im connecting to 95.45.*.*:8080

Comment: This doesn't sound like an Apache issue then, this sounds like a firewall issue. Are you sure port 8080 is exposed to the outside world? Try closing Apache and running node on port 80.

Comment: had it working there for a few minutes on port 80. Made some change sin the apache.conf file to allow for phpmyadmin to run because it was hitting node. And now it is gone again. So I don’t believe it is a firewall issue. Unless my isp are blocking it shortly after I connect?

Comment: Port 80 with apache off just loads a blank page. Also I just checked port 8080 with canyouseeme.org and it say it is open

Comment: Why do you need phpmyadmin to run? If port 80 worked and port 8080 is not then it is something on your system that is causing it. Check [here](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) to see if your port is available.

Comment: I need phpmyadmin because my app populates a database

Comment: phpmyadmin is for management of a database though. Your database is running on a different port and exists whether phpmyadmin is running or not.

Comment: I know I need to be able to manage my database. That is running on port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood properly, but if you want to access your localhost externally, you will want to use something like ngrock: 
[ngrock](https://ngrok.com/)

According to the description it created an Introspected tunnels to localhost

You just have to run it from your shell, for example `./ngrok 8080` if your server is listening on that port, then it will connect and provide you a link. With that link your localhost is accessible from everywhere around the web. It's useful to test webhooks!